# Is there any way to install packages to run my script in a remote ssh server without permission?

Tags: r, ssh, r-markdown

I have developed a .RMD (Rmarkdown) that generate a html output with the result of some statistical data.

I was running this file in my computer using this code:

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('File-name.Rmd')"
```

and it worked perfectly.

Although, my problem now is that I want to run this file on a server, connecting by ssh protocol and uploading this .Rmd with scp command , but I got this error:

```
    Error en loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’
    Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```

I have tried to install rmarkdown but I haven't got permission to install anything.

Comment: Can you write anywhere on the hard drive? I'm guessing you should be able to write to the temporary directory. Can you access the internet?

Comment: @sebastian-c sorry for the delay. Yes, I can.

Comment: Try using `install.packages` and install to a location you can access then use the `repos` argument of `library` to load it.